# (Eclipse C) File created in a random directory

Tags: c, eclipse, file

So, I'm kind of getting crazy over this but I have several problems.
Premise: I have Windows 10, and someone told me it could be it, but I still couldn't find anything like this on the internet.

The main problem is that when I create in write mode, the file appears in a random directory and not in my project's folder, like it should be. At first the file was created on the desktop, and now that I've reinstalled eclipse the folder is changed, but still isn't the project's one.

Secondly, and I think the two problems are correlated that's why I'm writing about both, when I try to run any code in Eclipse I get this message: 
**gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.**

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling both MINgw and Eclipse, but the situation hasn't changed a bit.

The test code I've been using to create the file is this:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *test;
    char string[11];
    test = fopen("testtest.csv", "wb+");
    if(test==NULL)
    {
        puts("Error");
    } else {
        fputs("ThisIsATest", test);
    }
    fclose(test);

    test = fopen("testtest.csv", "rb+");
    if(test==NULL)
    {
        puts("Error");
    } else {
        fread(string, sizeof(string), 1, test);
        printf("%s\n", string);
    }
    fclose(test);
    system("pause");
}
```

I don't know what to do to have Eclipse creating the files in the project folder.

Comment: Supposedly the file should be located in the same folder as the executable binary. But then Eclipse is simply a complete clusterf* when it comes to paths and folders. Consider using a different IDE.

Comment: Well, commonly it's said: Using Windows is the problem in the first place. :-D